# Google - Directory API (Admin SDK) Create Group - Error

Tags: python, rest, api, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface

I am currently following Google's [Python Quickstart for Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python#top_of_page) and experimenting with different ways of using the REST API's. The tutorial is designed to run within the Command Line and authenticates with O Auth 2.0 by creating a I have managed to change the code of the tutorial so that I can insert a user into a group that is already existing, by passing a groupKey of the group I am wishing to insert a User into and the body containing the email of the User I am adding, however, I cannot get [Create a Group](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups#create_group) to work.

The error that I am getting is:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission">
```

I am almost positive that my permissions within the Google Cloud Project are correct as I am a editor, and within G Suite I am a Super Admin. At first I thought I might of been pointing to the wrong Scope, but it appears that that is the recomended scope for creating the Group.

Could somebody please aid me in getting a group created, as I am very new to REST API's and wish to improve my own skills and understanding. Whether there has been an area that I simply misunderstood and need to go back and read on.

I have posted my code below:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'generic-app-name' # removed for example - imagine the name is included


def get_credentials():

    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'admin-directory_v1-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():

    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('admin', 'directory_v1', http=http)

    print('Creating Group For Testing')
    test = {
        "email" : "test@test.co.uk",  # Fake email for example
        "name" : "Test Group",
        "description" : "Just testing here."
            }
    group = service.users().insert(body = test).execute()
    return group

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thank you for taking the time to read the post and I hope to hear back from some of you soon,

***A hopeful programmer.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the link [The Google Directory Groups API for python](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/admin/directory_v1/python/latest/admin_directory_v1.groups.html) for create a group in Google Directory.

Comment: Here you go: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/quickstart/python

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after looking at the Error Logs within the Google Cloud project, rather a simple fix.
Before:

```
group = service.users().insert(body = test).execute()
```

After:

```
group = service.groups().insert(body = test).execute()
```

Here you can see that I have changed service.users to service.groups.

I cannot believe I let such a simple mistake get past me, but leaving on here incase this helps others.

Thank you